# How to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i\ge0\right)$?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, expected-value

I am trying solve
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i\ge0\right)$$
where $X_1,X_2,...$ are centered random variables, i.i.d, and $0<EX^2_i<\infty$.

I don't know where to even start with this.

Comment: What does centered mean in this case?

Comment: @Denis28 $EX=0$

Comment: If we use Hoeffding, we may bound the probability to $1/e$, maybe that may come useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Central limit theorem, [Classical CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT).

The classical CLT says that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n Var(X_1)}}\Big( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i-n\mathbb{E}[X_1] \Big) \overset{\text{dist.}}{\to} Z $$

where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. In your case $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$, $Var(X_1)=\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$, so

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{\text{dist.}}{\to} Z. $$

In particular

$$  \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \geq 0 \Bigg) =\mathbb{P}\big( Z\geq0\Big).  $$

You just need to connect the event $ \Big\{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i  \geq 0 \Big\} $ to the event $ \Big\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \geq 0 \Big\} $.

Comment: Hi! Firstly, thanks for answering. I rewrote  $\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$ as $\sqrt{n}\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}X_i}{\sqrt{n}}$ but I'm wondering what happens to $\sqrt{n}$ when we take the limit?

Comment: Well $\sqrt{n}$ tends to infinity. The thing that you should note is that the original sum is larger or equal than $0$ if and only if the 'new' sum is larger or equal than $0$.